# Jacobson radical of a direct product of matrix rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=M_5(\mathbb Z)\times M_3(\mathbb Z_8)\times M_3(\mathbb Z_3)$. How many elements has $J(R)$? (In this question $M_n(S)$ is referred to the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with elements in a ring $S$ and $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of ring $R$.)

I know that for any ring $R$ we have $$J(M_n(R))=M_n(J(R)).$$ 
For Jacobson radical and the direct product can we find an equality or inequality? For example the relation $J(A\times B)=J(A)\times J(B)$ can proved?

Comment: So, what do you know about finding the radical of a ring?

Comment: I know formal definition that state: "The Jacobson radical J(R) of a unital ring R is the intersection of the annihilators of simple left R -modules."

Comment: For commutative rings what you said can be reformulated as follows: the Jacobson radical is the intersection of all maximal ideals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that $J(A\times B)=J(A)\times J(B)$. Then use that $J(\mathbb Z)=(0)$, $J(\mathbb Z_8)=\hat 2\mathbb Z_8$, and $J(\mathbb Z_3)=(\hat 0)$.

Answer (score 2):

[image: you can see solve of this problem and for more question let me I know]

you can see solve of this problem and for more question let me I know

Comment: The OP already said that he knows that relation.

Comment: Where is this exact proof from?